# What is a way to return exception caught in asp.net Web Api to Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have my angular service like:

```
GetPaymentDeadlineExtension(data: PatientInput): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(
    this.root + `/api/PaymentDeadline/RegisterPatientInput`,data);
}
```

in my web api controller:

```
        [Route("RegisterPatientInput")]
        public SrvInvoiceCompositView[] RegisterGetPaymentDeadlineExtension(PatientInput data)
        {
            SrvInvoiceCompositView[] list = null;
            string ContractNo = String.Empty;
            string DktInvoiceNo = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                 ContractNo = data.BillNumber.Split('-')[0];
                 DktInvoiceNo = data.BillNumber.Split('-')[1];
                 list = DkService.SrvFindInvoiceCompositViewDentaPay(DktInvoiceNo, data.Amount, data.PatientNumber, ContractNo);


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // exception to be returned to angular app.
            }

            return list;
        }
```

and in my component.ts file:

```
    this.homePageService.GetPaymentDeadlineExtension(this.input).subscribe(
      data=>
      {
        this.patientInfo = data;
      },
      error=>
      {
        //i want to get my ex.message here, so i can display it
      }
    )
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to send a non-2xx response? That has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: Actually i dont know what  non-2xx response is, all I want is to return exception or exception message from asp.net web api to my error promise in angular app,

Comment: You should probably read up on the basics of HTTP APIs, then.

Answer (score 0):

```
        this.homePageService.GetPaymentDeadlineExtension(this.input)
.pipe(catchError((error)=> { handleError here}).subscribe(
    data=>
    {
      this.patientInfo = data;
    }
  )
```

More info: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch

Answer (score 0):

To get an error in RxJS `subscribe` method you have to return such a http response that doesn't have 2xx status code. Based on your code snippet Bad Request (400) could be a good choice for example. So on .NET Core side you need to return an `IActionResult` following way:

```
    [Route("RegisterPatientInput")]
    public IActionResult RegisterGetPaymentDeadlineExtension(PatientInput data)
    {
        SrvInvoiceCompositView[] list = null;
        string ContractNo = String.Empty;
        string DktInvoiceNo = String.Empty;
        try
        {
             ContractNo = data.BillNumber.Split('-')[0];
             DktInvoiceNo = data.BillNumber.Split('-')[1];
             list = DkService.SrvFindInvoiceCompositViewDentaPay(DktInvoiceNo, data.Amount, data.PatientNumber, ContractNo);
             return Ok(list); // This is has http status code 200 in the http response
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message); // This has http status code 400 in the http response
        }
    }
```

If you put in the Angular Component file following:

```
this.homePageService.GetPaymentDeadlineExtension(this.input).subscribe(
  data=>
  {
    this.patientInfo = data;
  },
  error=>
  {
    console.log(error);
  }
)
```

After a http request you will be able to see the exception message from the backend in the browser console.

I don't know exactly the use case of the developed software, but it is not recommended to display the exception on the frontend side in production. A hacker could extract some information from the server code with causing intentionally exceptions.

Comment: @Drasko any feedback?